# how to make a recursive function that shows how many vowels has an input

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion, char

I did manage to make a recursive function but for some reason the size of *char only gets to 8 and then stops

```
int vocales(char *cd,int num){

  if(num<=sizeof(cd)){

      if(cd[num]=='a' || cd[num]=='e' || cd[num]=='i' || cd[num]=='o' || cd[num]=='u'){

        return 1 + vocales(cd,num+1);

      }else{

        return 0 + vocales(cd,num+1);
      }

  }else{

     return 0;

  }
}
```

if i input "stackoverflow" it will only count until the 8th character so it says the amount of vowels is 3

Comment: Looks like you have a 64 bit system, and that you need to read up on what `sizeof` does.

Comment: sizeof should probably be strlen but I don't know if cd is null-terminated. and <= should probably be <

Comment: Since this is tagged C++ I'm going to suggest using std::string instead of a raw char*

Comment: Why do you want this to be a recursive function? This should probably be your first question...

Comment: @Macmade Recursion is a solution looking for a problem. It's probably an assignment. It seems quite elegant to me.

Comment: @nicomp A potential stackoverflow on stackoverflow... Quite elegant indeed...

Comment: _[Free debugging tip](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/):_ question the value of everything. You can check values via a debugger, or you can send values to `std::cout` to see them. Before the first `if` statement, check the values of `num` and `sizeof(cd)`. Before the second `if` statement, check the value of `cd[num]`. If you're puzzled by the values you see, search SO for an explanation, and ask if you don't find one.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof` returns the size of an object. In this case the object is a pointer, not the item pointed at. You need to find a new way of determining when the end of the string has been reached.

Fortunately C-style strings are null terminated, so you can look for the terminator instead.

```
int vocales(const char *cd) // no need for num.
                            // made cd const for a bit of extra versatility
{
    char val = *cd; // get pointed-at character just for readability
    if (val != '\0') // check for terminator
    {
        if (val == 'a' || val == 'e' || val == 'i' || val == 'o' || val == 'u')
        {
            return 1 + vocales(cd + 1); // advance pointer
        }
        else
        {
            return 0 + vocales(cd + 1);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

There is room for improvement, correctly handling uppercase vowels for example, but most of it the compiler [should be able to take care of for you](https://godbolt.org/z/edQrKB).

Answer (score -2):

You’re testing the sizeof a pointer instead of the size of the array

Edit:

```cpp
int vocales(char cd [],int num){

if(cd[num] != '\0'){

  if(cd[num]=='a' || cd[num]=='e' || cd[num]=='i' || cd[num]=='o' || cd[num]=='u'){

    return 1 + vocales(cd,num+1);

  }else{

    return 0 + vocales(cd,num+1);
  }
}else{

 return 0;
} }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198911/discussion-on-answer-by-h-s-how-to-make-a-recursive-function-that-shows-how-man).